# Project in a git subfolder

Tags: git, android-studio, github, intellij-idea

My question is two-part.

a). Suppose there is a repository on GitHub. One subfolder of that repository is an Android Studio project.

```
root/
  |
  + AS-project/
  + Other-files/
```

How can I work on it from within Android Studio? I know I can probably clone the repo and work on the project in Android Studio but I'll have to commit and pull from the outside of Android Studio. Not the best solution.

b). Conversely. If I begin from the other end and create an Android Studio project locally can I instruct it to upload it into a subfolder of a GitHub repo? So that I can make the commits and pulls from within the Android Studio? Or will I have to do it from the command line?

I am pretty new to git and only know the very basics of. And I am completely new to Android Studio.

Comment: This might not be a viable option but if possible you should move the AS-project out of this repository and into a separate repository used only for AS-project.

Comment: Android Studio has git integration; google can lead you to plenty of good articles on the subject. BUT I'm not sure if it will work well with a non-standard directory structure. As @gerard notes, you probably ought to have the AS project in its own repo (at root of repo). Then if you need it embedded in a bigger repo for some reason then use git submodules

Comment: I used google and AS documentation before I posted the question here. I didn't find a completely satisfactory solution.
Yes, I'll probably have to do as @gerard suggested. It was also my thought and I couldn't come with anything better.

Comment: Are you against using command line git? If not, using AS-project as a `submodule` might be a good way to go.  It would still involve moving the AS-project directory out and making its own repository but with some better git integration.

Comment: @tipanverella Not in generl. But if I'm working in Android Studio I'd like to use its VCS functionality. It feels wrong to have to change to a command line for a simple operation like push.

Comment: @Zeron the problem is that I don't know that the web-interface supports the creation of submodules.